# Need to move decimal point on float value

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to configure a decimal value so that it displays floats from 1 - 100, like 12.34. Right now, it is only displaying floats between 0 and 1, so that I am getting 0.12.

How to make the change so that the decimal moves two places to the right?

Here is the code for the method for iOS in Xcode 4.2:

```
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider
{
    NSLog(@"The value of the slider is now: %.2f", slider.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the interface designer, select your UISlider and change the value range (Minimum and Maximum):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, really dumb of me to forget that.

Answer (score 3):

Simply multiply it by 100

```
NSLog(@"The value of the slider is now: %.2f", slider.value*100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you multiply the value by 100?